# Common Lisp: How can I resolve an error I am receiving when trying to connect to mysql via cl-dbi?

Tags: mysql, common-lisp, quicklisp, cl-dbi

I would like to manipulate a mysql instance using cl-dbi, since I like Lisp and would like to avoid using a MySQL shell or use some other language.

Ubuntu 18.04

MySQL installed as part of a "Install LAMP and use WordPress" exercise.
Needed to rename s set of tables.

Realized I was using the MySQL shell, cut-and-paste, emacs, Sly, and some one-off defuns to do something that should be done programmatically via an abstraction layer that removes the need to care about a particular db software.

Read the "State of the Ecosystem 2015" and ql:quickload ed cl-dbi (Thanks, Hachiya-san!)

```
$ sudo mysql -V

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

cl-dbi as quickloaded two days ago

```
CL-USER> (defvar *connection*
  (dbi:connect :mysql
               :database-name "test"
               :username "yoozer"
               :password "bahsverd"))


;; result

Failed to find the TRUENAME of /home/gt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-dbi-20170725-git/src/dbd/mysql/error.lisp:
  No such file or directory
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "dbd-mysql" "src/dbd" "mysql/error">.
 1: [ACCEPT] Continue, treating compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "dbd-mysql" "src/dbd" "mysql/error"> as having been successful.
 2: [RETRY] Retry ASDF operation.
 3: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the configuration.
 4: [RETRY] Retry ASDF operation.
 5: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the configuration.
 --more--
```

Expected:

```
*connection*
```

Actual: as  above

### -

-

Another attempt based on Svente's comment:

```
CL-USER>  (ql:quickload :cl-dbi)
To load "cl-dbi":
Load 1 ASDF system:
cl-dbi
; Loading "cl-dbi"

(:CL-DBI)
CL-USER> (ql:quickload 'dbd-mysql)
To load "dbd-mysql":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    dbd-mysql
; Loading "dbd-mysql"
.
; Debugger entered on #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR "~@<~?~@[: ~2I~_~A~]~:>" {1003320DF3}>
[1] CL-USER
```

output in debugger buffer:

```
Failed to find the TRUENAME of /home/gt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-dbi-20170725-git/src/dbd/mysql/error.lisp:
  No such file or directory
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "dbd-mysql" "src/dbd" "mysql/error">.
 1: [ACCEPT] Continue, treating compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "dbd-mysql" "src/dbd" "mysql/error"> as having been successful.
 2: [RETRY] Retry ASDF operation.
 3: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the configuration.
 4: [RETRY] Retry ASDF operation.
 5: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the configuration.
 --more--

Backtrace:
 0: ((LABELS SB-IMPL::RESOLVE-PROBLEMATIC-SYMLINK :IN SB-IMPL::%QUERY-FILE-SYSTEM) "/home/gt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-dbi-20170725-git/src/dbd/mysql/error.lisp" 2 NIL)
 1: (TRUENAME #P"/home/gt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-dbi-20170725-git/src/dbd/mysql/error.lisp")
 2: (SB-C::VERIFY-SOURCE-FILE #P"/home/gt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-dbi-20170725-git/src/dbd/mysql/error.lisp")
 3: (COMPILE-FILE #P"/home/gt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-dbi-20170725-git/src/dbd/mysql/error.lisp" :OUTPUT-FILE #P"/home/gt/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.4.5.debian-linux-x64/home/gt/quicklisp/dis..
 4: (UIOP/UTILITY:CALL-WITH-MUFFLED-CONDITIONS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE*) {100331FC1B}> NIL)
```

etc...

### -

-
Noting the second line of the backtrace, I tried touching the ...error.lisp file.

Result:

```
gt@gt-ThinkPad-X230:~$ sudo touch /home/gt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-dbi-20170725-git/src/dbd/mysql/error.lisp
[sudo] password for gt: 
touch: cannot touch '/home/gt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-dbi-20170725-git/src/dbd/mysql/error.lisp': No such file or directory
gt@gt-ThinkPad-X230:~$ cd /home/gt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-dbi-20170725-git/src/dbd/mysql/
bash: cd: /home/gt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-dbi-20170725-git/src/dbd/mysql/
: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know what install should have created the dir and contents at    ...dbd/mysql/     and below?

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant in your case, but I found that I needed to check the 'ignore spaces' setting. So, in Data Sources (ODBC) (aka ODBC Data Source Administrator) ...
 
- click Configure for your chosen connection
- Details >>
- under the Misc tab, check/tick the box that says "Ignore space after function names"

Comment: Just a guess: maybe you need to quickload "dbd-mysql" first.

Comment: Strawberry, thanks.  I'm not familiar with ODBC.

Comment: Svante, thanks. This seems to be helping locate the problem. I've added to my original question, above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ rm -rf /home/gt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-dbi-20170725-git/
$ emacs

emacs: M-x sly
CL-USER> (ql:quickload 'cl-dbi)
To load "cl-dbi":
  Load 5 ASDF systems:
    bordeaux-threads cl-syntax cl-syntax-annot closer-mop
    split-sequence
  Install 1 Quicklisp release:
    cl-dbi
; Loading "cl-dbi"
[package dbi.error]...............................
[package dbi.driver]..............................
[package dbi].
(CL-DBI)
CL-USER> (ql:quickload 'dbd-mysql)
To load "dbd-mysql":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    dbd-mysql
; Loading "dbd-mysql"
..................................................
[package dbd.mysql.error].........................
[package dbd.mysql]..
(DBD-MYSQL)
CL-USER> (defvar *connection*
  (dbi:connect :mysql
               :database-name "test"
               :username "ab-user"
               :password "pass-bad-word"))
*CONNECTION*

disco
```